# Storage Backend based on Websockets

Tags: python, json, sockets, websocket, backend

I spent quite some time now with researching Server Backends/API/Frameworks. I need a solution where I can store user content (JSON & Binary data).
The obvious choice would be a REST API. The only missing element is a push feature when data on server changed and clients should be notified instantly. With more research in this matter I discovered classic approaches (Comet, Push, Server sent events, Bayeux, BOSH, …) as well as the „new“ league, Websockets. I would definitely prefer the method with Websockets or using directly TCP Sockets. But this post is *not* about pros/cons of these two technologies so please restrain yourself from getting side tracked in comments.

At moment exists following projects which are very similar to my needs: 

- Simperium (simperium.com), this looks very promising, but core/server is sadly not open source and god knows when, if ever, this step happens

- Realtime.co (framework.realtime.co/storage), hosted service, but same principle

- Some Frameworks for building servers such as Atmosphere (java, no WAMP), Cometd (java, project page looks like stuck in the 90’s), Autobahn (python, WAMP)

My actual favorite is the Autobahn framework (autobahn.ws). Especially using the WAMP protocol (subset of Websocket) as it offers exactly what I need. So the idea would be to build a python backend/server with Autobahn Python (based on Twisted framework) which manages all socket (WAMP) connections and include a Postgresql database for data storing. For all desired clients exists already WAMP libraries. The server would need to be able to do the typical REST API features:

- Send, update, delete requested data (JSON/Binary) from/to server/clients 

- Synchronize & automatic conflict management

- Offline handling when connection breaks, automatic restart when connection available again

So finally the questions:

- Have I missed an open source project which covers exactly my needs?

- If I would like to develop my own server with autobahn and a database, could you point me to right direction? Have lot of concerns and not enough depth understanding.. I know Autobahn gives you already a server, but this one is not very close to my final needs.. how to build a server efficient so that he can handle all connected sockets? How handle when a client needs server push? Are there schemas, models or concept how such a server should look like?

- Twisted is a very powerful python framework but not regarded as the most convenient for writing apps.. But I guess a Socket based storage server with db access should be possible? When I run twisted as a web ressource and develop server components with other python framework, would this compromise the latency/performance much?

- Is such a desired server backend with lot of data storage (JSON fields and also binary data such as documents, images) reasonable to build with Sockets by a single devoloper/small team or is this smth. which only bigger companies like Dropbox can do at the moment?

Thank you very much for your help & time!

Answer (score 0):

So finally the questions:

- Have I missed an open source project which covers exactly my needs?
  **No you've covered the open source projects. Open source only gets you about halfway there though. To implement a Global Realtime Network requires equal parts implementation and equal parts operations. You have to think about dropped messages, retries, what happens if a particular geography gets hot how do you scale your servers ...etc. I would argue that an open source solution won't achieve what you want unless you're willing to invest significant resources into operations. I would recommend a service like PubNub: http://pubnub.com**
- If I would like to develop my own server with autobahn and a database, could you point me to right direction? Have lot of concerns and not enough depth understanding.. I know Autobahn gives you already a server, but this one is not very close to my final needs.. how to build a server efficient so that he can handle all connected sockets? How handle when a client needs server push? Are there schemas, models or concept how such a server should look like? 
  **A good database to back a realtime framework would be Cassandra because it supports high write volumes and handles time series data well: http://cassandra.apache.org/.**
- Twisted is a very powerful python framework but not regarded as the most convenient for writing apps.. But I guess a Socket based storage server with db access should be possible? When I run twisted as a web ressource and develop server components with other python framework, would this compromise the latency/performance much? 
  **I would not use Twisted. I would use Gevent:http://www.gevent.org/. Its coroutine based so you don't get into callback hell. To support more connections you just increase your greenlet pool to listen on the socket.**
- Is such a desired server backend with lot of data storage (JSON fields and also binary data such as documents, images) reasonable to build with Sockets by a single devoloper/small team or is this smth. which only bigger companies like Dropbox can do at the moment?
  **Again I would not build this on your own. A service like PubNub: http://pubnub.com which takes care of all the operational issues for you and has a clean API would service your needs with minimal cost. PubNub takes care of the protocol for you so if your on a mobile device that doesn't support WebSockets it will use TCP, HTTP or whatever the best transport is for the device.**